# android 5.0 ask for security warning while open.camera

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-security

Please see this attachment. 
[image]

Why I see this on my screen, I am using all permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: That dialog is not part of standard Android. It is specific to whatever device you are using. You will need to contact the device manufacturer for details about this dialog.

Comment: Yes, This is what I facing problem my code is to open camera and when call Camera.open() it pop ups this dialog and in other device Camera.open() returns null.

Answer (score 0):

### Disable the Third-Party "App Permissions".

I was running into the same thing with some new rugged Android tablets our company purchased for field inspections.

Even though I'm requesting and checking permissions, I still get these security messages coming up. I thought this was part of standard Android but [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) is correct, it's part of a custom build of Android that includes an additional layer of "permissions management".

You can find it at Settings > Security > App Permissions.

[image: App Permissions in Security Section]

From there you can manage the each permission and what apps have what permissions.

[image: Permissions]

Here's the kicker, even when an app specifically has a permission, that notification window still comes up. The only way to not see that notification window is to check off "Do not remind again."

I *believe* that this is a way of "reminding" users that an app is doing something, even after they have given permission to it.

My solution, just turn it off completely. It's a nuisance, is not stock Android and is confusing to the user.

Now, for other users that might have this, I do not believe there is a way to check for this. I Googled and could literally only find your question referring to this odd permissions window.

Good luck!